# What does "fodder for a fight" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "They couldn't reach an agreement"?
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fodder?q=fodder+
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fodder

"The negotiations foundered over multiple issues, but labor and the environment were not trouble-free. The reason was that the United States does not come up with brand new outlines of trade agreements every time it sits down with a partner. Each agreement builds on its predecessors. Thus, even with an advanced partner like the EU, whatever language was adopted on labor and the environment would be a strong candidate for a new trade standard, even when applied to countries with weaker protections. Hence, there was still **fodder for a fight**."

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/phillevy/2017/07/09/why-a-us-uk-trade-quickie-is-very-unlikely/#43e934cd20e8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it means there are still things to fight over, unresolved issues, new demands and such.

An equivalent expression would be:

> Hence, there were still plenty of items to argue over.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Google's definition of *fodder*:

> food, especially dried hay or feed, for cattle and other livestock.

So *fodder for a fight* is something that will feed or fuel a fight.  The fact that it is livestock food and could provide additional implications or subtexts to what the author is saying.